# MATLAB: Compute mean over a huge array

Tags: matlab, performance, mean

I need to compute the mean of all columns over a huge array wherby I must replace all numbers that are less than zero with zero in the first place. Using my toy example, it will become obvious that these computation takes quite an amount of time.

```
tmp = -5 + 10 * rand(5000,100000);

tmp(tmp<0) = 0;
result = mean(tmp);
```

I am wondering whether there might be a better way in order to gain some speed?

Comment: You are not taking into consideration only non-negative numbers. You are substituting negative numbers by 0, which is a different thing. Also, you are computing the mean of each column; is that what you want?

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, that's exactly what I want.

Comment: In other words, `a=[-10 -10 10 11]`. You want the "positive mean" of `a`, `10.5`, but the way you are doing it you are taking the mean of `[0 0 10 11]` which is `5.25`. Try `result=mean(tmp(tmp>=0))`

Comment: @AnderBiguri I actually need to replace all negative numbers with zeros and I would be heading for the 5.25 in your example.

Comment: Do you need the mean of the columns of the matrix, or do you expect a single value in `result`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I need the mean of the columns, i.e. `result` should be a row vector of size `1 x 100000`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding values in arrays and then replacing them is a very expensive operation. Instead, do the following:

```
% slooooooow
tic
tmp(tmp<0)=0;
mean(tmp);
toc

% faaaaaaaaaast
tic
tmp=max(tmp,0);
mean(tmp);
toc
```

In my PC , this reports:

```
Elapsed time is 5.940434 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.358057 seconds.
```

Remember that if you expect a single mean value, you should call `mean(tmp(:))`